# Why my app is not available on the Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900F (5.1 inches - 432dpi)?

Tags: android

I want to support only smartphones but I see on console that my app is not avaiable for large screens with xxhdpi: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s5-6033.php

My AndroidManifest contains this:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="600"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"/>

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480"/>

</compatible-screens>
```

, comaptivle-screen is more restrictive.

Could you point out which params I should consider to support my samsung?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of android:screenDensity="480", can you try android:screenDensity="430" (or even 420)? In the Samsung Galaxy page it says its density is around 432.

Comment: 480 should be fine as it was mentioned in others topic, it is somewhat average which is in boundaries of xxhdpi. Actually I have tried it either but it doesn't help